# Loading a new ViewHolder based on click event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Within RecyclerView, any tips on loading a different viewholder onitemclick? i'm having trouble wrapping my head around loading viewholder 2 when item is clicked in viewholder 1 at that position. both viewholder 1 and 2 are a list of cards. so say for example. vh1 contains a sample hotel image. When you click that vh2 shows you contact details of that hotel - at that position, while retaining vh1 through out the other un-clicked contents.

I did ask a question like this before and i think it was a bit vague so people suggested i change information based onitem click. The problem is vh1 and 2 are different layouts completely so this wouldn't work for what i'm working on.

is this even possible?
Thanks

Comment: This could be done somehow. Do you have any code that you've started working on?

Comment: I do, but it was mostly following this link in order to get both viewholders setup. [Link To Codepath guide,](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView) then implemented onclicklistener and a boolean in order to switch views. So far i have click on any card = entire list changes. not sure how to change it based on position as yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another adapter for your `RecyclerView`. Create a new Java class, call it whatever you want. In your main activity, or the activity where you're setting your adapter, you can create a function like this:

```
public void setNewAdapter() {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.your_recyclerview_id);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    NewAdapter adapter = new NewAdapter(// any arguments);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

In your adapter, you can create a new instance of your activity. For example, if you're activity is called `MainActivity`, you can add this code in your `onItemClick`:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
mainActivity.setNewAdapter();
```

See if that works.

Comment: Hi Razor. Thanks for the reply. This isnt working as it reloads the entire list with new items. What i basically need is to load a different view at a specific position when user clicks. so eg. user clicks card A and cad b is loaded at that specific position while the rest of the layout retains the same elements. Almost like those cards that when clicked, get expanded. in this instance trying to go a step further and load a view while retaining state for the rest of the list.. I'm trying something suggested in terms of animations.. will let you know if it works :)